# MariaDB on AWS RDS curiously takes up 60GB of storage occasionally in a very short span of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a small MariaDB RDS Instance running on AWS. Every once in a while, the instance quickly starts to use the available storage (not the tablespace) and becomes 100% full, i.e. 100% storage full. Then it's locked by AWS, storage optimization happens and all that storage is released. I want to be able to debug this problem, but I don't have a clue why the DB would end up with full storage? Any clues to help me diagnose this? Where should I go look?

Now the Write IOPs suggest that I'm writing a ton of data to the DB. But that's mostly 'select' statements on a DB that's 400 MBs worth of data. ALL the temporary storage used is released after RDS is done with optimization. Is there a fix?

[image: Write IOPS]

[image: Storage Data]

[image: CPU Data]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have a database with 60GB of storage, you say you insert a couple of hundred GB of data, and you're not sure why it's filling up? It looks like you're just using the database. Perhaps you could edit your question to make things a bit more clear? AWS Support can be very useful for cases like this.

Comment: I must have been sleeping when I did that post. Made corrections

Comment: Ah, makes a bit more sense now. I'm not a DB expert, but I wonder if it's some sort of query or transaction log that's flushed. Given that disk space isn't all that expensive I'd try increasing the disk and seeing what happens. Take a snapshot first, you can restore later to the smaller database size if you need to.